# Custom Deck of Cards from a Picture folder (no repetitions of already played cards)

Tags: python, pycord

So I'm currently writing a code (pycord) for a custom card game discord bot. At the moment, I still have to draw the cards IRL and deal them to the players with a "-hand [Name]" command. I'm trying to make this progress a bit easier by getting the bot to deal random cards from my file folder. However, IDK how I'll get the bot to never deal the same card twice. Any ideas?

also thank you for the help I can't upvote your comments because I don't have reputation yet!

Comment: you could add cards dealt to some set/list so its never dealt again, when the cards run out then allow them to deal again?

Answer (score 0):

Store your files in a list, get a random index and remove the card with said index from the list.

```
from random import randint
import os

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]

def get_random_card():
    index = randint(0, len(files) - 1)
    file = files[index]
    del files[index]
    return file

random_card = get_random_card()
```

Note that the list in this example only stores the file names.